# Jquery Image Zoom for All Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, zooming

I found a jquery image zoom plugin on the web (http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom) but I have more than 200 small images that I would like to apply this plugin. 
I think I need to track mouse on elevatezoom.js, how can I do that?

HTML

```
<img id="zoom_01" src="image1.png" data-zoom-image="image1.jpg"/>
```

Script

```
<script> $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom(); </script>
```

(elevatezoom.js file can be found on http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/download-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

First, give a `.class` to handle all images

```
<img class="image-to-zoom" 
     id="zoom_01" src="image1.png" data-zoom-image="image1.jpg"/>
```

Then, attach to the `.class` the `mouseover` event to trigger `elevateZoom()` on the element has the mouse hover

```
$('.image-to-zoom').on('mouseover',function(){
    //This element is being 'mouseovered', so trigger the plugin
    $(this).elevateZoom();
});
```